# Quick Time screencast slows down my gameplay also size too big

Tags: macbook-pro, video, screen-capture, quicktime

I recorded few of the videos in past with quicktime. Size of those videos is too big  (~5GB). I have a macbook pro 15-inch retina version. For cutting down the size I am using `HandBrake`. With that a 2 GB video would come up to 45MB but then video resolution goes really down. Is there any other recording software that can record videos at relatively smaller size?

Comment: Have you considered [Camtasia](http://www.techsmith.com/camtasia.html)?

Comment: No @bassplayer7 i didn't knew its for mac as well

Comment: You had two questions in here. This site works better when there is only one question per question. That way, it's easier for other people to find solutions if they have the same problem. I've edited out your second question, but feel free to ask it separately.

Comment: Did you try different HandBrake settings? Lower size means lower resolution, fewer frames per seconds, reduced image quality or a combination therefore.

Comment: @patrix yes but size doesn't go down significantly